# Removing one edge from Graph

Tags: graph-theory

How many new graphs that are not isomorphic will I have by removing any of its edges (but only one!) ? 
[image]

I did following: 
[image]

Where the numbers mean which graph will I get by removing corresponding edge. When the numbers are the same that means that removing edges with same number will create same graph ( = isomorphic) 
My answer would be 6 graphs, but in the key there is 5 as answer.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Removing 1 or 3 produces isomorphic graphs, so in total you get 5 possible graphs under isomorphism :)

Comment: @wircho Ahh, that's true, my bad. Thanks :-/

Comment: @wircho: Perhaps you could convert that comment to an answer and get this question off the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above:

Removing 1 or 3 produces isomorphic graphs, so in total you get 5 possible graphs under isomorphism :)